# Issues while Installing bugzilla in windows server

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to install `bugzilla 5` in windows server. (Why do people still use windows during development? :( ). I'm with linux most of the time and I'm unable to understand official instructions for installing `bugzilla` in windows. [I'm following this official page for installing bugzilla.](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/windows.html) I'm configuring `postgresql` for bugzilla by using [this link.](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/postgresql.html#postgresql)
I'm able to log into postgresql from terminal as shown here:
[image: img]
Then I ran this command:

```
createuser -U postgres -dRSP bugs
```

Then I got this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "createuser"  
LINE1: createuser -U postgres -dRSP bugs
```

How can I create a new user `bugs` and assign him/her certain permissions? New user (bugs) will not be a superuser (-S) and will not be able to create new users (-R). He/She will only have the ability to create databases (-d).

Comment: Tried it here on my Win machine and it worked wo a problem.

Comment: `createuser` is a **command line** command, you don't enter that in the SQL client (psql in your case). Plus there is no `--help` option for the **SQL** statement `create user`. See the manual if you need to see the full syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you have already connected to `postgres` database and need to run smth like this `CREATE ROLE roleName LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'passwd';` for `createuser` use the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-createuser.html)